# make circles(buffers?) on openlayers

Tags: geometry, openlayers, point, geoserver

I am sorry for the awkward grammar because I am not good at English.

I want to make circles at each point(load from url)
I used ol.source.imageWMS, but i don't know how to get each point's latitude, longitude.

this is my code:

```
Source_PtSearch = new ol.source.ImageWMS({
    url : 'http://localhost:9090/geoserver/HB/wms',
    params : {'LAYERS' : 'HB:HB_ASF_TEST2'},
    serverType : 'geoserver',
    crossOrigin : 'anonymous',
    projection : 'EPSG:4326'
});
```

how can i get each point's latitude, longitude?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make a [GetFeatureInfo](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/GetFeatureInfo/index.html) request to your Geoserver to retrieve all features from a WMS layer. Then have a look at [WMS GetFeatureInfo Example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/getfeatureinfo-layers.html) to see how to parse the response to get all Features, in resume it's:

```
var allFeatures = new WMSGetFeatureInfo().readFeatures(response);
```

Then you can iterate over all features and get the coordinates by:

```
feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates()
```